# Por que no me deja hacer un casting?

Tags: java, excepciones, herencia, casting

Que tal, estoy intentando representar una función en java y cree un clase para representa seno,cos etc... que es hija de la clase Termino, luego almaceno cada termino en un ArrayList. El problema es que al ejecutar me manda esta excepcion

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: metodo.biseccion.Termino cannot be cast to metodo.biseccion.TerminoTrig
f(x)=   at metodo.biseccion.Funcion.mostrarFuncion(Funcion.java:36)
    at metodo.biseccion.MetodoBiseccion.main(MetodoBiseccion.java:24)
C:\Users\Gerardo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)`

No entiendo por que no me deja hacer el casting, alguien podra ayudarme? Dejo el codigo de mis clases

Clase Fucnion: Aqui es donde me marca la excepcion, en la linea donde hago el casting

```
package metodo.biseccion;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Funcion {
private int grado;
private ArrayList<Termino> polinomio;

public Funcion(int grado){
    this.grado=grado;
    polinomio = new ArrayList<>();
}
public void agregaTermino (double coeficiente, double exponente){
    Termino t = new Termino(coeficiente,exponente);
    polinomio.add(t);
}
public void agregaTerminoTrig(double coeficiente, double exponente, int tipo){
    TerminoTrig t = new TerminoTrig(coeficiente,exponente,tipo);
    polinomio.add(t);
}
public void mostrarFuncion(){
    System.out.print("f(x)=");
    for(int i=0;i<polinomio.size();i++){
        double exp,coef;
        Termino t=(Termino)polinomio.get(i);
        if(t instanceof Termino){
            TerminoTrig t2 = (TerminoTrig)t;
            switch (t2.getTipo()){
                case 1:
                    exp=t.getExponente();
                    coef=t.getCoeficiente();
                    System.out.print(coef+" Sen"+"^"+exp+"(x) +");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    exp=t.getExponente();
                    coef=t.getCoeficiente();
                    System.out.print(coef+" Cos"+"^"+exp+"(x) +");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    exp=t.getExponente();
                    coef=t.getCoeficiente();
                    System.out.print(" "+coef+"Tan^"+exp+"(x) +");
                     break;
            }
        }
        else{
            exp=t.getExponente();
            coef=t.getCoeficiente();
            System.out.print(" "+coef+"x^"+exp+" +");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Clase Termino (Padre)

```
package metodo.biseccion;
import java.math.*;

public class Termino {
protected double coeficiente;
protected double exponente;

public double getCoeficiente() {
    return coeficiente;
}

public double getExponente() {
    return exponente;
}

public Termino (double coeficiente, double exponente){
        this.coeficiente=coeficiente;
        this.exponente=exponente;
}

public double obtenerValor(double x){
    return (Math.pow(x, exponente)*coeficiente);
}
}
```

Clase Hijo

```
public class TerminoTrig extends Termino{
private final int tipo;

public TerminoTrig(double coeficiente, double exponente, int tipo) {
    super(coeficiente, exponente);
    this.tipo=tipo;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 */
public int getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public double ObtenerValor(double x){
    switch (tipo){
        case 1: 
            return (Math.pow(Math.sin(x),exponente))*coeficiente;
        case 2:
            return (Math.pow(Math.cos(x),exponente))*coeficiente;
        case 3:
            return (Math.pow(Math.tan(x),exponente))*coeficiente;
        default:
            System.out.println("El tipo de funcion es incorrecto");
            return 0;
    }
} 
}
```

Quisiera aclarar que ni siquiera he hecho pruebas con el tipo de datos sen,cos,tan, de hecho si comento es parte corre muy bien, por lo que el error sale sin ni siquiera meterle datos.

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontre el problema, al parecer se trata de un mal uso de mi parte del operador instanceof, debe de ser t instanceof TerminoTrig. De todas formas gracias a la persona que respondio

Answer (score -1):

El problema puede estar en tus constructores, dado que tienes una clase `Termino` sin constructor, toma la de por default que es

```
public Termino() {

}
```

Ahora en `TerminoTrig` que extiende de termino al momento de crear el objeto no se puede dado que solo puedes crearlo con los parámetros que necesita el constructor y que el objeto termino no los tiene

```
public TerminoTrig(double coeficiente, double exponente, int tipo) {
    super(coeficiente, exponente);
    this.tipo=tipo;
}
```

La solución sería crear otro constructor genérico donde los parámetros no sean necesarios

```
public TerminoTrig() {

}
```

Con esto debería poder dejarte hacer el cast

Comment: Disculpa tal vez mi codigo esta un poco desordenado, pero Termino y TerminoTrig ambos tienen constructores, el de Termino esta despues de los get. Ya intente lo que me dijiste y no me deja poner otro constructor vacio suponto que por que al menos debo llenar los parametros de la clase padre

Comment: Crea dos constructores vacíos ambos en cada clase, o intenta creando uno sin tipo en TerminTrig()

Comment: ya lo intente y parece que no funciona :(